# Suggest combobox text when user type any text

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have a combobox that is fill by a column data from database. I had set Autocomplete property is true and mode is Suggest. It is working well but problem is that in my database column data there are thousands of name and when user is typing text then combobox is suggesting the text according to Alphabetical order. I want when user type any keyword like `'and'` then it should suggest only that words or data who contains `'and'` keyword. None of data should not be suggest.
 I had already worked on `combobox1_keypress` event and try so many thing but i found only negative result. Please suggest me how can i resolve this problem and provide the best solutions to my client.

Or if there is any way how to put javascript and jQuery in Windows Forms Application then tell me.

Comment: Why are you using combobox ? I would suggest to use **Textbox** for auto suggest feature instead of combobox.

Comment: now i have develop with `comobox` and now i can't change in whole project. so i have to work with `combobox`

Comment: There is no need to put js or jquery in winform. Can you please post some existing code that you have written so far?

Comment: Can you solve my problem because i have tried so many code but i din get the right result.

Comment: That's why i m asking you to put some code so that either me or somebody here can give you some hint or at least identify where you done any wrong...